# Matching proxyauth.so version to PHP Zend API version

Tags: php

This is the error every time I start up php:

> Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/proxyauth.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/proxyauth.so, 9)

I have two older versions of the proxyauth.so in no-debug-non-zts-20060613 and no-debug-non-zts-20090626, but neither is compatible with a module API compatible with 20100525, so symlinking doesn't solve the problem.

I've Googled my best and have no idea where proxyauth comes from, and therefore can't make a new one with the compatible API. There doesn't appear to be an extension in the php ext directory, so I have no idea what to do next.

Thoughts?

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 0):

If the warning is the only problem - meaning your code itself runs fine - then the extension isn't required anymore by your application. Why not out-commenting the `extension=proxyauth.so`?